# No map received SLAM Toolbox

Tags: ros2, slam, rviz

I want to use SLAM Toolbox (https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox) but I get a WARNING: No map received in RVIZ.

- In the config file, I define base_frame as **base_footprint**
- I publish Odometry (without velocities, just position) to topic /odom
- I provide transform:
  odom->base_footprint
- I publish to topic /scan
- I run:

`ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_sync_launch.py`

`rviz2`

**RESULT:**

- In **rviz I add /map topic**, no map received
- In console with slam_toolbox I got only following warning:

[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1661430634.973317229] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'cloud' at time 1650563651.362 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'

**Questions**

1. Should I be receiving a map or have I missed something?
2. Could not providing a transform for the scanner frame be the issue?

   Warning, transforms and rqt graph follows:

[Warrning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJmXR.png)

[Frames transforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9UOu.png)

[Rqt graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2BcS.png)

**EDIT**

odom->base_footprint was static transform, now it is set properly

Comment: hello, please how did you set the odom->base_footprint properly. i am struggling at that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It should not work
2. Transform for scanner frame is necessary

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).